# How to Add Songs to a SongCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, media-player

In my application I am using the MediaPlayer to play songs from the users MediaLibrary. However I can't add songs to a song collection once I have defined it!

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create or modify a `SongCollection` with the current SDK.

Comment: Is there some other type that I can modify and play with MediaPlayer then?

Comment: If you mean you want to create your own playlists, you'll need to create your own from scratch (for example, with a List<Song>) and it won't work if the user closes your app as the MediaLibrary is not supported in the BackgroundAgent. So if the currently playing song finishes, there's no way of loading the next song from your list if your app is running in the background.

Comment: ah okay I'll give it a go anyway though, however I tried creating a `List<Song>` but the MediaPlayer wouldn't accept this as a valid type, not would it let me use `(SongCollection)List<Song>`, do you know anything else I could try?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The current SDK is way too limited in what developers can do with it in terms of media player access IMHO. You won't be able to convert to `SongCollection` and you won't be able to pass `List<Song>` to the MediaPlayer. Instead, you need to somehow monitor when a song has changed (maybe using [these events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer_events.aspx)) and then get the next song in your list and play that. Essentially you're playing one song at a time from your list.

Comment: When the user presses "next" or the song ends, you simply move to the next item in your List and play that. However, your app always has to be in the foreground for this to work. As you can see from this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019526/implementing-playlists-with-songs-from-phone-storage-windows-phone) there doesn't seem to be a good way of creating a mediaplayer atm.

Comment: Oh I see, we'll thanks for all the help. This seems to add a lot of problems to creating my music player app

Comment: You're welcome. I've been in the same boat and have spent a lot of time trying to find workarounds for my media player but it turned out the thing I wanted just weren't possible :/

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, it is possible to add or delete songs to the `MediaLibrary` but only on Windows Phone 8 as a new set of [`MediaLibraryExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.medialibraryextensions_members%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx) were introduced...

- [MediaLibraryExtensions.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.medialibraryextensions.delete%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx)
- [MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.phoneextensions.medialibraryextensions.savesong%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using List<>

```
List<SongCollection> lstAlbum = new List<SongCollection>();
```

And then :

```
using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
{
    foreach (Album item in library.Albums)
    {
        lstAlbum.Add(item.Songs);
    }
 }
```

Hope this help !