# How to add mp3 files to a MediaPlayer.Queue, or otherwise play a list of mp3 files sequentially on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, media-player

**Background**

I have a folder containing .mp3 files on my device, stored in `/Resources/raw`. I need to play some of these files sequentially under certain circumstances.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
foreach (var track in _tracks)
{
    var name = track.Item1;
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", "/Resources/raw", name), UriKind.Relative);

    var song = Song.FromUri(name, uri);

    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    // only the last track plays because the foreach loop is too fast
    MediaPlayer.Play(song); 

}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working because `MediaPlayer.Play()` plays the song in a separate thread and the `foreach` loop just fires each one as fast as my processor can let it. As such, it only ever plays the last track.

I've tried adding a delay, e.g. `Thread.Sleep(1000);` before each call to Play() but that has had no effect.

I can see that `MediaPlayer` has a `Queue` property and `MoveNext()` method, which plays the next song in the queue. However, I can't figure out how to add the list of files to the Queue.

**Question**

How can I get songs into that Queue so that I can play them sequentially? Is this the best way to achieve the result I need? If not, what should I do to play the mp3 files sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually worked (though not ideally) was to increase the Thread.Sleep() time to something longer than the track. I initially wasn't using a long enough value:

```
foreach (var track in _tracks)
{
    var name = track.Item1;
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", "/Resources/raw", name), UriKind.Relative);

    var song = Song.FromUri(name, uri);

    Thread.Sleep(2000); // this value has to be longer than the track

    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();        
    MediaPlayer.Play(song); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't.

For some unknown reason Microsoft does not allow the developper to create a custom playlist on Windows phone.

[Implementing playlists with songs from phone storage [windows phone]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019526/implementing-playlists-with-songs-from-phone-storage-windows-phone)